# ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-sparse (on virtualenv)

Tags: python

I have a virtualenv in Pycharm running Python 3.7.9, I'm using Microsoft Windows 11 Home as the OS on a x64-based PC. I'm trying to run a program that uses the Simulation package, to install this package I need to install scikit-sparse, but when I try to install scikit-sparse it says that it can't build wheel. The main error in the stacktrace is:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cholmod.h': No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Edit: The stacktrace is:

```
 running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse
      copying sksparse\test_cholmod.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse
      copying sksparse\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1033.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1033_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1850.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1850_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1033.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1033_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1850.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1850_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\sksparse\test_data
      running build_ext
      building 'sksparse.cholmod' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\sksparse
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isksparse -IC:\Users\caiul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env
-3mmxvfbx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Users\caiul\Desktop\Projects\Thesis Project\multisbc_cluster_mu_gym\venv/include" -I/usr/include/suitesparse "-IC:\User
s\caiul\Desktop\Projects\Thesis Project\multisbc_cluster_mu_gym\venv\include" -IC:\Users\caiul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\caiul\AppData\Local\Program
s\Python\Python37\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcsksparse/cholmod.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\sksparse/cholmod.obj
      cholmod.c
      c:\users\caiul\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(203): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-sparse
Failed to build scikit-sparse
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-sparse, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Can you show your full stacktrace? Please post as text not image starting from the word 'Traceback'.

Comment: I edited the stacktrace into the original question

Comment: Did you notice the error is different? I don't know what that means though

Comment: It might help to add the exact command you ran

Comment: Sure, the command I ran was:  pip install scikit-sparse

Comment: would you be open to use Conda?

Comment: I tried, but within the virtual environment that I'm using the terminal says it can't find a version of conda to install. I tried the command "pip install conda"

Comment: can you see if this link helps you? https://github.com/EmJay276/scikit-sparse